# Postgresql 9.3: Cannot read data from a certain host

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a master and a slave database with streaming replication. From my local machine, I can connect to the master via psql and describe tables and everything works fine. However, from my web server, I can connect to the master fine, but when I run `\d`, it freezes. I can't cancel the command, it just freezes. I have to force quit the ssh session to exit. The same thing happens when I try to tab complete.

I can read from the standard postgres views, such as `pg_stat_activity`.

I can connect and read data just fine from the slave, on both local and the web server.

I'm using the same user and database on local and web, and `pg_hba.conf` allows that user/database combo from anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say something about your assumptions based on your observations is wrong, as it seems very unlikely that they are explainable.  Freezing psqls is usually a result of locks -- do you see any with `pg_stat_activity` or `pg_locks` while it's 'frozen'?  Is anything else connected to the db while you're trying this from the web server?  Is there yet another box you can test from?

Comment: The only thing I see in `pg_stat_activity` is itself (`select * from pg_stat_activity`), and `pg_locks` has this:

Comment: `locktype  | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid  |      mode       | granted | fastpath
 relation   |    16384 |    11090 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 2/99               | 14412 | AccessShareLock | t       | t
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 2/99       |               |         |       |          | 2/99               | 14412 | ExclusiveLock   | t       | t`

Comment: Is that pg_locks data there whether you're describing tables from master or not?

Comment: For future reference, please add command output etc as edits to your questions. It's way easier to read. My first guess, like Scott, would be an exclusive lock held somewhere, but it's pretty hard to see what'd affect `\d` and not everything else. I would be checking the server's `dmesg`, and probably `strace`'ing the backend to see what it was doing when it got stuck, or attaching `gdb` to see what it was doing.